# Why do Selenium Python tests look so weird?

Tags: python, selenium

I've used the Selenium IDE to generate some test code for my application. The generated Python code for an assertion looks like this.

```
    try: self.failUnless(sel.is_text_present("Path"))
    except AssertionError, e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
```

Instead of failing fast, the error is added to a list, and the script continues.

I was wondering what the rationale for this is? Isn't it better to fail fast? Or would this leave the page in an inconsistent state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the difference between a `verify` and an `assert` in Selenium. When using `verify` any failures will be logged but the test will continue, they are in effect a 'soft assertion'. If you want to stop executing your test on a failure try using `assert` instead.

```
//verifyTextPresent
try: self.failUnless(sel.is_text_present("My Text"))
except AssertionError, e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))

//assertTextPresent
self.failUnless(sel.is_text_present("My Text"))
```